# Combine two arrays of different dimensions in Google script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have two arrays one has m dimensions mArr and the other has n dimensions nArr and I want to  append the smaller mArr to the larger nArr at the end

```
mArr = [[NewH], [DD1], [DD2], [DD3], [44]]

nArr = [[Id, H1, H2, H3], [1.0, aa1, bb1, cc1], [2.0, aa2, bb2, cc2], [3.0, aa3, bb3, cc3], [4.0, aa4, bb4, cc4]]
```

I need

```
result = [[Id, H1, H2, H3, NewH], [1.0, aa1, bb1, cc1, DD1], [2.0, aa2, bb2, cc2, DD2], [3.0, aa3, bb3, cc3, DD3], [4.0, aa4, bb4, cc4, DD4]]
```

Some of the things I have tried:

```
values = transpose([mArr,nArr])

and
if ( mArr.length > 0 ) {

  var i = 0;

  while ( i < mArr.length ) {

  nArr.push(mArr[i]);
  i++;
  }
 }
```

I guess these only work for same dimensional arrays

Thanks

Comment: 1. Provide [mcve]. Quote the strings in your arrays. `mArr = [[NewH], [DD1], [DD2], [DD3], [44]]` is not reproducible. `mArr = [["NewH"], ....]`. 2.There's also `DD4` is not present in `mArr`, but it's present in result. 3. And `m===n===2`. Only two dimensions are present in both arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Array.map

```
nArr.map(function(row, i){
  return row.concat(mArr[i]);
})
```

```js
mArr = [[1],[2]];
nArr = [[4,5], [5,6]]
result=nArr.map(function(row, i){
  return row.concat(mArr[i]);
})
console.info(result);
```